# jquery .on() event for multiple other events all triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I want an event handler which only runs when multiple other event handlers are completed. Is there any simple way to do this in jQuery? What I have is working fine, however it seems unnecessarily complicated.

https://jsfiddle.net/sguah2e4/1/

```
<div id="el1">waiting for element 1 ...</div>
<div id="el2">waiting for element 2 ...</div>
<div id="doneStatus">waiting for both to complete ...</div>

<script>
$(window).on('load', function() {
  initMultiHandler();
  updateEl1();
  updateEl2();
});

function initMultiHandler() {
  var event1Done = false;
  var event2Done = false;
  $('#el1').on('fetched', function () {
    event1Done = true;
    if (event2Done) allDone();
  });
  $('#el2').on('updated', function () {
    event2Done = true;
    if (event1Done) allDone();
  });
}

function updateEl1() {
  $('#el1').text('element 1 is done!').trigger('fetched');
}

function updateEl2() {
  $('#el2').text('element 2 is done!').trigger('updated');
}

function allDone() {
  $('#doneStatus').text('both are complete now');
}
</script>
```

Note that the type of event will not be the same for each element - hence the difference between `fetched` and `updated` in my example here.

Ideally I would like a 1-liner something like this instead:

```
function initMultiHandler() {
  $.on($('#el1').on('fetched') && $('#el1').on('updated'), allDone);
}
```

Is there anything like this available in jQuery?

Comment: have you looked at jQuery.when()? https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: good point. [here is the solution using deferreds](/q/5009194) however its no more simple than the one i posted in the question. i was hoping for a 1-liner.